# How to generate .net classes from Access tables

Tags: .net, ms-access

Is there any way that I can get my .NET classes to be automatically generated from the tables in Access?

Anything like ORM available?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use an ORM such as nHibernate, here's a partial older list of ORM's http://www.theserverside.net/news/thread.tss?thread_id=29914

Or you could use code generation techniques, such as CodeSmith http://www.codesmithtools.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can add a **DataSet** to your project (Add New Item) and then drag-and-drop your tables onto the dataset-view. This will automatically generate classes for the tables.

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate is supported on Microsoft Access:
http://www.hibernate.org/

LINQ to SQL and Entity Framework do not support Access.

Comment: I didn't think Entity Framework cared what the DB was?  Or is this a designer issue?

Answer (score 0):

MyGeneration got some Templates for Automatically generate Classes from Access Tables.

http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/portal/default.aspx

Comment: At least with NHibernate you've got the support knowing that this is a product that is tried and tested.

Comment: Yes, but you can use both MyGeneration and NHibernate to generated hbm xml files and classes :)